# Solaris. xterm display problem

Tags: unix, x11, xterm

I connect to a solaris (10) server through SSH from my linux machine.

However, when I attempt to open another terminal using " xterm" , then it does not work.

I set the DISPLAY env variable to 127.0.0.1:0.0, but it gives the following error:xterm Xt

> error: Can't open display: 127.0.0.1:0.0

Please suggest a solution to rectify this.

Thanks

-Mike

Answer (score 2):

That's the address of the X server on the target machine.  You need to address the X server on the client machine on which you're working. The *easiest* way is to just use ssh -X or -Y, (see *man ssh(1)*) as

> **client**: ssh -Y solaris
>
> > *in order to connect to the remote machine; you need login info too*

This just sets up an X connection, tunneled through ssh.

Otherwise, you can do it by hand as

> **client**:
>   $ echo $DISPLAY
>   client:3:4
>
> > *remember it's not *always* 0.0*
>
> $ xhost +solaris
>
> > *You have to allow connections from the remote machine*
>
> $ ssh solaris
>
> > *sets up a remote shell, you still need ssh login info*
>
> **solaris**:
>   $ export DISPLAY client:3.4
>
> > *make sure its the server on 'client' you're using*
>
> $ xterm
>
> > This should now give you a 'solaris' xterm window on 'client'

Comment: Thought it would; I use it all the time to work on my Solaris box from my Mac desktop.  Annoyingly, there are versions of ssh around that want the -X argument instead; keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1):

As Charlie mentioned, use *ssh -X hostname* when connecting.

If all else fails enter *xhost +* on your remote machine. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Set the display to your linux IP address, not localhost.

127.0.0.1 is localhost : therefore on the Solaris server, it's the server itself.